# Google Speech API from the browser

Tags: google-speech-api, google-cloud-platform

In the documentation page https://cloud.google.com/speech/ there is a demo example that listens to speech via the browser and uses the API in the background. Is the source for this demo available?

If not, the speech API uses flac files. Is there any open source project that can record flacfiles from the browser (that is compatible with this API - there are many github projects out there but wondering if there is an official one)?

Comment: If it helps anyone we open sourced this as a project https://github.com/gridcellcoder/cloud-speech-and-vision-demos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case it helps someone, this approach is a good start to start recording audio from the browser:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/recognize.js

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/recording-audio/#acquire_access_to_the_microphone

and 
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

**Edit:** The solution was open-sourced as its own project:  https://github.com/gridcellcoder/cloud-speech-and-vision-demos

Comment: hey @devl, did you ever find a way to stream directly from the browser to Google's Speech API?

Comment: @KhonMar Yes we did, and open sourced a project from it https://github.com/gridcellcoder/cloud-speech-and-vision-demos

Comment: This information is a bit outdated, and it doesn't really answer the question. First link is 404 now. Second link is about access to microphone in browser. Third link is four recording. Fourth link doesn't actually go to Speech-to-text from browser. It actually goes browser --> NodeJS server --> Speech-to-text

Comment: @devl when trying demo I have error language not supported ?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can get the source code in any language for the speech api from google cloud platform github link:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/

Comment: Thanks though this is the general API client libraries. I'm looking for the exact code for the part "Convert your speech to text right now" in the browser, do you know if that exists?

Comment: yes brother ,you can use these libraries they are useful for converting speech to text in browser : https://talater.com/ https://responsivevoice.org/ hope you mark my answer as useful :)

Comment: nice site but we have to develop our own solution and cannot send data externally. We need a library to record flac from the browser that is compatible with speech api.

Answer (score 0):

You can call from browser with simple functions like or you can read this article [Google Speech APIs from broweser](https://medium.com/@ali.anwar33/google-speech-apis-cloud-text-to-speech-and-cloud-speech-to-text-apis-from-browser-react-js-0773c9edc9d1)

```
    // Text to Speech Example
async function googletextTobSpeech (text: string): Promise<string> {
       
try {
        const apiKey = getGoogleApiKey();
        if(!apiKey || !text) return;
            
        const url =  `https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=${apiKey}`;

            const data = {
                'input':{
                  'text': text
                },
                'voice':{
                  'languageCode':'en-gb',
                  'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
                  'ssmlGender':'FEMALE',
                },
                'audioConfig':{
                  'audioEncoding':'MP3'
                }
              };

              const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
              });

              const responseJson = await response.json();
              const audioBlob = toBlob(responseJson.audioContent, 'audio/mpeg');
              const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
              return audioUrl;

        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error)
        }
```

}